# How to continuously update to database server with JDBC in Java without increase the amount of RAM consumption?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I write a fighting game in JavaFX, using JDBC to update information to a MySQL database. Most tasks that get basic information from the database server will work properly if not repeated continuously. The problem occurs when I need for the program to constantly update information from the opponent, such as position, level, damage in the game. I have to send select commands to the server continuously, which increases the RAM used by the thread running these commands.

```
void startUpdatingOpponentInfo() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        while (matchID != -1) {
            String query = String.format("select * from matchDetails where matchID = %d and userID = %d", matchID, opponentID);
            try {
                ResultSet resultSet = sqlConnection.getDataQuery(query);
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    double opponentX = resultSet.getDouble("xPos");
                    double opponentY = resultSet.getDouble("YPos");
                    if (opponentX != -1 && opponentY != -1)
                        opponent.move(canvas, new Position(opponentX, opponentY));
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    });
}

  public ResultSet getDataQuery(String query) {
    Statement statement;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(query);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultSet;
}
```

I tried searching a few methods and found one that was quite helpful. After each select, I will let that thread sleep for a period of time and then select again. This way increases performance significantly, the amount of RAM consumption remains stable. However, it is not suitable for querying information that always needs to be refreshed, because RAM consumption is still high with a short sleep of 'select' thread. Is there any useful method for this problem, where I allow my game to connect directly to the database server without going through an intermediate game server.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Don't just interpolate values into a query string. In this case you're relatively safe because the interpolated values are numbers, but if you apply this pattern anywhere else with strings, then you have a problem.

Comment: One problem in your code is that you don't close the result set. You don't show the code of `getDataQuery`, but if you make similar mistakes there, you're probably also leaking connections and statement objects.

Comment: You aren't closing your `ResultSet`s. Whatever `sqlConnection.getDataQuery()` may do, it may be leaking `Statements` or `PreparedStatement`s. You may also be leaking `Connection`s. This is a textbook example of how not to write JDBC code.

Comment: How many Threads are created?

Comment: Re your edit, as suspected, you are leaking not only `ResultSet`s but `Statement`s as well, especially in the event of an exception. Returning a `ResultSet` from a method basically cannot be done. You should put the body of `getDataQuery()` inside the thread block where it is called, and use try-with-resources to ensure the `ResultSet` and the `Statement` get closed. @RickJames It wouldn't matter if there was only one thread: there are still leaks.

Comment: I have already change all in my code, with Try-With_Resources, it really helps me. But I wonder is there any way to shorten my code, I see that any where I want to select, I need to try(Statement, ResultSet..). If I create function to get dataquery as I did in my question, it is impossible to close resultset and statement because it return resultset, and I need to use it in other position. Do I need to answer my question? Thank all of you.

Comment: That's exactly what I am telling you to do, and I also told you that returning a `ResultSet` from a method basically cannot be done, as you have just discovered. You have to use a try-with-resources structure, or else return a `CachedRowSet`, but that has its own disadvantages, notably a potentially waste of space.

Comment: @user207421 You can return result set without leaking a statement, by calling the `closeOnCompletion()` method of the `Statement` object. Then when the result set is closed, it should (assuming JDBC 4.1 compliance) close the originating statement as well.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Indeed, indeed, and a compliant impllementation is supposed to release all resources on closing the `ResultSet`, which presumably includes the `Statement`, but he needs to start by closing the `ResultSet`, and once he has the try=-with-resources structure in place it would be madness not to include the `Statement` in that as well.

Comment: Are you seriously using a *database* to track a real time game state? Why not just do it in memory

Answer (score -3):

You should first try an optimisation of your variables.

Your thread keeps using new String for the query, whereas it seems it could be build only once. Same for your ResultSet, each time you run into a new loop, you will use a new place in RAM for a new object.

You can check this by adding a console out of your Java ID object :

```
System.out.println(resultSet);
```

And see it's different each time

Something like this :

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {

        ResultSet resultSet;
        final String query = String.format("select * from matchDetails where matchID = %d and userID = %d", matchID, opponentID);

        while (matchID != -1) {
            try {
                resultSet = sqlConnection.getDataQuery(query);
```

Then I let you think about changing your Query, to select only the xPos/yPos not equals to "-1" and get a result only for a real opponent position changing, and finaly, maybe not sending a "new Position" but only the 2 variables opponentX and Y, which will prevent your RAM to store this object.

Don't forget that Java will clean your RAM objects only when your code execution is done (in short version), so having a single never ending thread won't go into this case.

Comment: You don't have any choice but to use a new `ResultSet` per iteration, and your code doesn't change that: you are conflating reference variables with objects. And creating lots of `Strings` isn't a problem unless you are retaining references to them, which the OP isn't.

Comment: " Java will clean your RAM objects only when your code execution is done": this also is false.